# Tamanho tabela não diminui

Tags: mysql

Uma tabela do mysql tinha 10.2Gb de dados,
Rodei um script que apagava dados antigos que já não eram necessários,
Após apagar metade dos dados dessa tabela, ela ainda continua com 10.2Gb.
Consumindo o HD do meu servidor.

Como ou o que faço para reduzir o tamanho dessa tabela ?

Comment: O banco não realoca memória quando você deleta um registro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você deleta um registro, está simplesmente avisando que aquele espaço está livre.

Seria impraticável um DB ficar encurtando o arquivo em produção, pois isso significaria rearranjar todos os dados internamente (similarmente a uma desfragmentação de disco).

Se realmente precisa disso, de alguma forma precisa "remontar" a tabela.

### Solução *built-in* para InnoDB e MyISAM

O MySQL possui o `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, que entre outras coisas, reorganiza os dados internamente:

```
OPTIMIZE [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL] TABLE tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
```

Ele funciona para a maior parte dos usos, e o comportamento muda um pouco entre InnoDB e MyISAM. Não funciona para outros *engines*, tenha isto em mente.

- No InnoDB ele reorganiza índices e tabela no caso específico de você usar um arquivo por tabela (`.ibd` individual).
- No MyISAM já é feita a desfragmentação completa.

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

### Solução "manual" para uso geral ou "controlado":

Se for um banco que pode ser parado por um instante, uma solução é simplesmente fazer um *dump* da tabela e recriá-la importando os mesmos dados:

> FAÇA BACKUP E **TESTE** O BACKUP ANTES DE TENTAR ISTO!

```
mysqldump db_name t1 > dump.sql
mysql db_name < dump.sql
```

Para fazer em todas as tabelas:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
mysql < dump.sql
```

Se precisar manter o DB em produção, uma solução intermediária é criar uma tabela com a mesma estrutura, e usar um

```
 SELECT * FROM tabela INSERT tabela2
```

e ao final, renomear as tabelas, depois descartando a antiga.

O cuidado, neste segundo caso, é que você precisa dar um jeito de travar a original contra escrita, pois alguém pode inserir ou modificar um dado enquanto está ocorrendo o INSERT. Esta segunda solução é mais adequada quando você pode bloquear a escrita, mas precisa manter a leitura.